# Maximum depth of trees

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

When finding the maximum depth of an N-arr tree, the approach differs slightly from that of a binary tree.

Binary tree max depth:

```py
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        if not root:
            return 0
        
        else:
            left_depth = self.maxDepth(root.left)
            right_depth = self.maxDepth(root.right)
            
            return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1
```

In contrast, the n-arr tree:

```py
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        if root:
            if root.children:
                child_depths = list(map(self.maxDepth, root.children))
                return max(child_depths) + 1
            else:
                return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

I could not get the n-arr approach to work until I added the `else: return 1` lines. I'm curious why isn't this "root exists but children do not exist" logic required of the binary tree max depth approach?

Comment: You don't need the `else: return 1` if you replace `return max(child_depths) + 1` with `return max(child_depths, default=0) + 1`

Comment: @Stef, what does the default parameter do? I gather it returns a value when the function/method is called w/ a None type payload...or something different?

Comment: In the case of a binary tree, there are always 2 children. In the general case of a tree with lists of children, the number of children might not only be a positive integer, but also 0. You have to tell `max` what to return if there are no children. That's the `default` argument.

Comment: Note: this is not an n-ary tree. An n-ary tree is a tree where every node has exactly n children. For some n. For instance, a binary tree is a 2-ary tree.

Comment: @Stef, copy on the max default argument. Why is this not required/relevant for the binary tree case? Both methods use the max function. Perhaps an empty list is treated differently than `max(None, None)`

Comment: For the binary tree, there are always two children. You never call `max` with an empty list. But in the variable-number-of-children tree, you allowed empty lists of children. So you need to tell `max` what is the max of an empty list, cause that's a pretty special case. Note that some definitions of binary trees do allow a node to have no children. Some definitions say "in a binary tree, every node has either no children, or exactly two children". In your definition, every node must have exactly two children, but some of those children can be "None" instead of a node.

Answer (score 0):

From @stef's comments I've pieced this together, which works

```py
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        
        if root:
            child_depths = list(map(self.maxDepth, root.children))
            return max(child_depths, default=0) + 1

        else:
            return 0 # no children
```